# Regex (.*) and random string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I changed the Permalink on WP to get any strings after the path. I use the regex: "yourdomain.com/%postname%-(.*)/"

When I am checking: "yourdomain.com/%postname%-f46eb54b99ce3a9835ea7d63e075d434", it matches.

But when I check: 
"yourdomain.com/%postname%-446eb54b99ce3a9835ea7d63e075d434" then it returns "yourdomain.com/%postname%-(.*)/446/".

I think (. *) Will fit in everything, regardless of letters or numbers. I appreciate anyone who can explain it to me.

Comment: `.` is any character `*` between zero or unlimited times

Comment: What do you mean, _then it returns "yourdomain.com/%postname%-(.*)/446/"_ …? Where does “it” return that, and to whom? Do you mean the user gets redirected in their browser, or …?

Comment: Presumably there is an additional rule somewhere which is looking specifically for numbers, and it's taking precedence. You might get better expertise about where this is happening on the dedicated sister site at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Add regex (. *) Allow me to add any strings after the path. However, if a string starts with a letter, it will display the end of the string. But if it starts with a number, it will not show the end of the string. Thanks for all the feedback

Comment: You view on .* is correct. You have errors in other places look the answer. Welcome on SO and +1 for a question of decent quality for a novice.

Comment: People, please, what is unclear here? Your closing votes are very strange.

Comment: @RongRêu Please, rewrite the 3rd paragraph. What do you mean by "it returns"? The problem is understandable even so, but you shouldn't use so undefined phrases.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape all / and ., if you mean them as normal symbols. So, you'll have:

```
 yourdomain\.com\/%postname%-(.*)\/
```

It must not match

```
 yourdomain.com/%postname%-f46eb54b99ce3a9835ea7d63e075d434
 or
 yourdomain.com/%postname%-446eb54b99ce3a9835ea7d63e075d434
```

, because you regex **demands** / at the end. If it is not obligatory, put ? after the ending `\/`.

```
yourdomain\.com\/%postname%-(.*)\/?
```

[tests](https://regex101.com/r/hfiDH0/1)